# Is there any way to share same data for multiple widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple Widgets that pass same data for another Widget, is there any way to reference these data arguments so I can add and change that from one place?

```
 PostHeader(
postTitle: apiData.getPostTitle(index),
postDate: apiData.getPostDate(index),
postImageLink: apiData.getPostImageLink(index),
postContent: apiData.getPostContent(index),
authorID: apiData.getAuthorID(index),
postLink: apiData.getPostLink(index),
)

PostCard(
postTitle: apiData.getPostTitle(index),
postDate: apiData.getPostDate(index),
postImageLink: apiData.getPostImageLink(index),
postContent: apiData.getPostContent(index),
authorID: apiData.getAuthorID(index),
postLink: apiData.getPostLink(index),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest solution is to use the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) Package,
where you can add on the top of your widgets list and using `notifyListeners` you can share the data all over your app.

You can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkFjtCov62g) how to use it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you can, either create a static class and set your data in a property, or you can use BLoC design pattern to share the data using streams / sync